# Finding carrying capacity and estimating a constant from Logistic Equation

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have data, say population of a country A during several periods of time. For example I have $10$ people living in the country at year $1, 20$ people at year $2, 35$ people at year $3, 41$  people at year $4$ and so on, with no particular pattern, except that it's growing. The logistic equation $$P(t)=\frac{K}{1+Ae^{-kt}},$$ 
where $A=\frac{K-P(0)}{P(0)}$, $K$ is carrying capacity, $k$ is a constant, which is unknown, and $t$ is time (in this case year of a particular event). I am curious how I can find $K$ and $k$ from knowing population at each year, please nudge me in the right direction. What are the ways to apply R or octave here?

Comment: Please verify the edits. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).